# @mixin format is it ok to not have ()?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Learning about `@mixin` and I came across this code. How come the `hover-not-disabled` on the first line is not followed by `()` and is it ok to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
@mixin hover-not-disabled {
      &:not([disabled]):hover {
        @content;
      }
    }
    .button {
      border: 1px solid black;
      @include hover-not-disabled {
        border-color: blue;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fine. It won't cause any errors, since `(…)` is meant to contain the `arguments` which when using a `@mixin` are *usually* needed, *however* in this case the editor wants to pass the mixin into mutliple elements and then edit the `@content`.

From a subjective point of view, I'd recommned to always include the `()` for the sake of consistency even if they would be empty, so when quickly scanning the code, nothings seems odd.

---

So this would be my approach, but generally spoken, it's totally fine to leave them in such cases.

```
@mixin hover-not-disabled() {…}
```

```
@include hover-not-disabled();
```

Comment: I agree with you, so that when others look at it they'll find it easy to read too, thanks!